# How do I add softsubs to a .avi file?

Tags: video, subtitles

I have a .srt file with the desired subtitles and I want to merge it into the main file.  I want them as soft subs, though, and I haven't seen anything that says how to do this.  All I can find is how to do them as hard subs.

Edit:  Turns out that for me it's basically a moot point anyway, while the target machine supposedly plays .avi files I have not been able to get it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

mkvmerge will gladly mux subs with video. The only thing is that you'll be left with a .mkv after, which may not be a problem.

Comment: I tried this one also--nope, I'm getting boxes instead of subtitles.  At least it behaved a lot more sensibly than the AviAddXSubs option.

Comment: Is the file encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: I don't know the encoding.  It displays properly in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add soft subs to an .avi file easily by a free tool called [**AVIAddXSubs**](http://www.calcitapp.com/AVIAddXSubs.php). See [this tutorial](http://www.instantfundas.com/2009/02/how-to-add-soft-subtitles-to-divx-movie.html) which explains the details.

Comment: Sounds like it, trying it now...

Comment: ...nope.  It can't cope with the track.  I tried both Default and ChineseBig5 (the track I'm trying to add is Chinese) and both produce ??????'s instead of captions.